# Too many arguments in spark RDD.takeOrdered in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, arguments, rdd

I get this trying to compile with sbt

```
sbt test
```

[info] Loading project definition from /home/shared/Aalto/SCC/As1/rdd/project
[info] Set current project to rdd (in build file:/home/shared/Aalto/SCC/As1/rdd/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/shared/Aalto/SCC/As1/rdd/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /home/shared/Aalto/SCC/As1/rdd/src/main/scala/questions/GeoProcessor.scala:174: too many arguments for method takeOrdered: (num: Int)(implicit ord: Ordering[(String, Long)])Array[(String, Long)]
[error]             txt = txt.zipWithIndex.takeOrdered(txt.count.toInt-2, ((a,b) => a._2 > b._2))

And I don't see that 3rd argument it's saying I have.
What I wanted to do is take all the elements but the 2 first (not sure if for that is correct the > or if it should be an < instead).
If it's not possible to do it like this, what other good way would there be? I already tried with subtract, the problem is that it returns them with a random order. Thank you.

Comment: Next time, please include the _code_ that causes the exception explicitly - it's hidden in the error message and hard to locate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
import scala.math.Ordering

rdd.takeOrdered(n)(Ordering.by(_._2))
```

or

```
rdd.takeOrdered(n)(Ordering[Long].on(_._2)
```

Comment: I tried that but still not working, now it gives me:
sbt test
[info] Loading project definition from /home/shared/Aalto/SCC/As1/rdd/project
[info] Set current project to rdd (in build file:/home/shared/Aalto/SCC/As1/rdd/)
/home/shared/Aalto/SCC/As1/rdd/src/main/scala/questions/GeoProcessor.scala:174: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Array[(String, Long)]
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
[error]    txt = txt.zipWithIndex.takeOrdered(txt.count.toInt-2)(Ordering[Long].on(_._2))

Comment: Basicly type mismatch, found Array(String, Long), required RDD(String)

Comment: Ah okay, but that's because of the assignment, it's fine now then, thank you!

Comment: For what I wanted to do there's needed an .reverse too before the .on or the .by, but it was basically that.